# stack navigator stacking views

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following setup for navigation

```
//Main
export const Router = StackNavigator (
    {
        Welcome : { screen : Welcome},
        App: { screen: App }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName : 'Welcome'
    }
);

const App = StackNavigator( 
    {
        page : {screen: Tab}
    }
);

const Tab = TabNavigator( 
    {
        page1 : {screen : page1},
        page2 : {screen : page2},
        page3 : {screen : page3}
    },
    {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        animationEnabled: false,
        swipeEnabled: false,
        tabBarComponent: ({navigation}) =>
        <TabBar navigation={navigation}
            iconsMap={{ Explore: 'visibility', Home: 'home', Profile : 'settings' }}/>
    }
);

const page1 = StackNavigator(
    {
       subview1 : {screen :  subview1},
       subview2 : {screen :  subview2}
    }
);
```

The page gets displayed alright but when I click the `page1` button on the tab, my views on the top are stacked over and over e.g., page1, page1 etc.,

Is my design wrong here or can I use some option to restrict the views from stacking ?

The behaviour I want is when I click the `page1` icon on the bottom, the view changes but if I click anything in the view above they should be stacked and not the entire view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete my old content due to your new edit.

Here is my tab navigator setup:

```
class Tab3 extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: '3',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (<Icon name="apps" color={tintColor} />),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {renderSomething()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const InnerChatNavigator = TabNavigator({
  ['chat/tt1']: { screen: Tab1 },
  ['chat/tt2']: { screen: Tab2 },
  ['chat/tt3']: { screen: Tab3 },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'chat/tt1',
  navigationOptions: {
    // headerStyle: styles.header,
  },
  tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: false,
    activeTintColor: uiTheme.header.activeTintColor,
    inactiveTintColor: uiTheme.header.inactiveTintColor,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: uiTheme.header.backgroundColor,
    },
  },
  tabBarComponent: TabBarTop,
  tabBarPosition: 'top',
  swipeEnabled: false,
  animationEnabled: false,
  backBehavior: 'none',
});
```

`<Icon/>` is from `react-native-material-ui`, and `{ TabBarTop } from 'react-navigation';`, the only bigger difference seems like `tabBarComponent`? Not sure if that `navigation` props of your `TabBar` results in weird behavior.

Comment: typed in hurry, but I made sure it was like so. I edited the post now.

Comment: @PavanK Got it. Could you try to add `initialRouteName` for every navigator? I suffer a lot from react-navigation as well and found this to be a kinda safe plus.

Comment: added that, doesn't work ... page1 basically gets stacked over and over

Comment: @PavanK Got it. Edited my content, see if there is any help :/

Comment: you are right, navigation props were causing trouble. Not sure why though :(

Comment: I used tabbarbottom and it works now without stacking